# LibreOffice Base not opening in 14.04

Tags: libreoffice, 14.04

Just tried to open up `Base Database` under LibreOffice suite by to my surprise nothing happens. All the other programs (Writer, Calc, Impress, Math) open and work accordingly.

How can I rectify this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The welcome screen shows the "**Base Database**" option but actually **Base** is not installed by default (See the [14.04 manifest](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.manifest)).

Open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) to install the missing package, then type:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-base
```

Now you should be able to open the **Base Database** application:

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot both of you (for question and answer). I filed a bug with libreoffice for this: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=79835

Comment: It is so strange and unintuitive that the button is there in the launcher and simply fails silently when pressed instead of throwing some user feedback.

Answer (score 3):

## Try resetting LibreOffice.

Open your Terminal and execute this command:

> rm -r ~/.config/libreoffice