# Is Libreoffice built in?

Tags: libreoffice

As I am installing ubuntu in a computer which is not connected to the internet I need to know if Libreoffice is builtin.
Thanks

Comment: Yes! And a bunch of other tools also.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

On a fresh installation you can create all types of LibreOffice documents/objects except a **Base** database (See [LibreOffice Base not opening in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453728/libreoffice-base-not-opening-in-14-04/453771#453771)).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can check the list of software installed in a live environment using the [manifest](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.manifest) from the Ubuntu Releases website. This contains a few packages such as GParted which are not part of the actual installation, but for most packages this list is enough.

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice is a part of Ubuntu, therefore it will install as part of Ubuntu installation.